# clearing the setInterval in the onScreen plugin to change a class when in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm using the [*onScreen Plugin*](https://github.com/benpickles/onScreen) to change a class on an element when it is scrolled to viewport. I would like to remove the class after a few seconds even if the element is in the viewport and when the element is not in the viewport the element should not have the class like the way the plugin is designed (I think).

so when the user scrolls to the element the class should be added to show that this the element that the user is looking for. Then it should be removed after a few seconds to show that it is regular content on the page.

I think I noticed in the plugin that when ever the element is in the viewport a setInterval constantly adds the class so I tried to clear the interval so it wont set the class but it's not working.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( function() {
        var id = setInterval( function() { ("#link").removeClass("red").filter(":onScreen").addClass("red").delay(2000).queue(function() {
           $(this).removeClass("red");
            });
        }, 1000 );

   });
   function remove() {
      if ( $("#link").hasClass("red") ) {
          setTimeout(function() { clearInterval( id ); }, 3000 )
          $("#link").removeClass("red");
      }
   }
   remove();
```

please help me remove the class when the element is in viewport after a few secs and  after the added class was displayed. Thanks for your help.

Here is the [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WkESu/).

Comment: Its because id variable is not global

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use this [plugin](http://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/) instead. It has two methods that you can use to do stuff to the matched elements as they enter or leave the viewport like so:

```
$('#link').onScreen({
  doIn: function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
  },
  doOut: function() {
    $(this).removeClass('red');
  }
});
```